# jcarousellite circular items help with cloned items

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

Hey guys, I am using the jcarousellite to display items that are set to circular so it scrolls back around...However the items that scroll around are actually clones and dynamically generated so when those items are in view, I can't click on them and pull the title via jQuery because they seem to not be bind...

So does anyone know how to live bind those items with this plugin?

Comment: @wdm - why should i accept answers that are not working for me? I will not blindly accept just to get my percentage up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I dug through the code and researched the clone function and it turns out I just need to add clone(true) to the plugin and that will bind the cloned items to the parent dom element.